# Kivy - Dynamic text markup?

Tags: python, dynamic, markup, kivy

I've been learning Kivy for the past month or so; having a blast but this one's got me really stumped. I have a lot of text, and I need Kivy to highlight those words that exist in a glossary I have written, and when those words are clicked, open a popup with the appropriate definition. I have a bit of code that does almost just that, but no matter which word I click, I get only a popup with the definition for 'crab':

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty, DictProperty, ObjectProperty

sentence = 'For breakfast today we will be having cheese and crab cakes and milk'

my_gloss = {'crab':'a beach-dwelling critter',
        'milk':'leads to cheese when processed',
        'cheese':'the processed milk of a given ungulate',
        'breakfast':'the first meal of the day',
        }

class GlossaryGrabber(Widget):

    sentence = StringProperty(sentence)
    glossary_full = DictProperty(my_gloss)
    gloss_curr_key_list = ListProperty([])
    new_sentence = StringProperty()
    definition_popup = ObjectProperty(None)
    glossary_def = StringProperty()

    def highlight_terms(self):
            self.gloss_curr_key_list = self.glossary_full.keys()
        sent_copy = self.sentence.split(' ')
        for i in self.gloss_curr_key_list:
            if i in sent_copy:
                sent_copy.insert(sent_copy.index(i), '[ref=][b][color=ffcc99]')
                sent_copy.insert(sent_copy.index(i) + 1, '[/color][/b][/ref]')
                self.glossary_def = self.glossary_full[i]
        self.new_sentence = ' '.join(sent_copy)

class GlossaryApp(App):

    def build(self):
        g = GlossaryGrabber()
        g.highlight_terms()
        return g

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GlossaryApp().run()
```

And its complimentary .kv file:

```
<GlossaryGrabber>:

    definition_popup: definition_popup.__self__

    Label:
        text: root.new_sentence
        center_y: root.height/2
        center_x: root.width/2
        markup: True
        on_ref_press: root.definition_popup.open()

    Popup:
        id: definition_popup
        on_parent: root.remove_widget(self)
        title: 'definition'
        content: def_stuff
        BoxLayout:
            id: def_stuff
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                 text: root.glossary_def
            Button:
                text: 'go back'
                on_release: root.definition_popup.dismiss()
```

Obviously the glossary_def string that hooks up to the popup's content is being overwritten at each iteration over the sentence copy, but I can't pass any sort of 'ref=X' because the tag itself is contained in the string. Is there any way to give each word a separate identifier? Or is there a better way to go about this? I need to be able to pass the program any string for the 'sentence', and any glossary dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

When you click a ref, kivy tells you which ref was clicked. You need to use this to decide to display the correct text in the popup. You don't seem to set the text at all after a click.  A second issue, is that you don't name the refs.

Following is some changes which should make it work:

```
markup: True
on_ref_press:
    root.glossary_def = root.glossary_full[args[1]]
    root.definition_popup.open()
```

And:

```
for i in self.gloss_curr_key_list:
    if i in sent_copy:
        sent_copy.insert(sent_copy.index(i), '[ref={}][b][color=ffcc99]'.format(i))
        sent_copy.insert(sent_copy.index(i) + 1, '[/color][/b][/ref]')
```

Comment: Your solution worked beautifully! I see that I was attempting to refer to the text selected outside of the on_ref_press event, it makes so much more sense to handle everything there. Thank you!